# Divs move downwards when padding expands on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have two divs, when one hovers over the text (which are links) of a div, the padding increases from 0 to 5px. My issue is that whenever I hover over the text and the padding increases, the divs move down. Here's the code:

```
<div id="container" class="text1">
<a id="text1style" href="#" style="font-family:arial;font-size:120%;
text-decoration:none;">Some text</a>
</div>

<div id="container" class="text2">
<a id="text2style" href="#" style="font-family:arial;font-size:120%;
text-decoration:none;">text</a>
</div>


#container {
position:relative;
}


a:link, a:visited, a:active {
color:blue;
}


a:hover {
color:yellow;
}


.text1box {
left:200px;
bottom:35px;
width:243px;
}


#text1style {
-webkit-transition:color 0.5s;
-o-transition:color 0.5s;
-moz-transition:color 0.5s;
-ms-transition:color 0.5s;
transition:color 0.5s;
-webkit-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-o-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-moz-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-ms-transition:background-color 0.5s;
transition:background-color 0.5s;
}


#text1style:hover {
padding:5px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color:red;
}


.text2 {
left:455px;
bottom:57px;
width:90px;
}


#text2style {
-webkit-transition:color 0.5s;
-o-transition:color 0.5s;
-moz-transition:color 0.5s;
-ms-transition:color 0.5s;
transition:color 0.5s;
-webkit-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-o-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-moz-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-ms-transition:background-color 0.5s;
transition:background-color 0.5s;
}


#text2style:hover {
padding:5px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color:red;
}
```

**Updated code**: I have applied the padding expansion to the individual links, instead of the div, and this has helped out. I still have two issues: 1) The texts (of links) still shift slightly to the right. 2) When I remove the mouse (i.e: hover ends) you can see that the text has lost padding and border radius as the background (red) fades away.

How could I resolve these two issues? Many thanks.

Comment: An ID should only be used once, you can however have multiple classes by doing class="class1name class2name"

Comment: @HarrisJT Please see updated code for alternative resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by moving the 2 boxes upward to compensate for the padding moving them downward.

*And `id` should be unique*

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
  -o-transition: color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.5s;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.box1 {
  left: 200px;
  /*bottom: 35px;*/
  width: 221px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box2 {
  left: 455px;
  /*bottom: 57px;*/
  width: 66px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.container:hover {
  top: -5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.container.box1:hover + .box2 {
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="container box1">
  <a href="#" style="font-size:120%;
text-decoration:none;">Some text</a>
</div>

<div id="container2" class="container box2">
  <a href="#" style="font-size:120%;
text-decoration:none;">text</a>
</div>
```

Based on question edit, updated with a 2:nd sample, where I added `padding: 0 5px` to the `a:link` rule to compensate for the hovered padding

```css
#container1, #container2 {
  position: relative;
}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: blue;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.text1box {
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 35px;
  width: 243px;
}
#text1style {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
  -o-transition: color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.5s;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
#text1style:hover {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.text2 {
  left: 455px;
  bottom: 57px;
  width: 90px;
}
#text2style {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
  -o-transition: color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.5s;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
#text2style:hover {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="text1">
  <a id="text1style" href="#" style="font-family:arial;font-size:120%;
text-decoration:none;">Some text</a>
</div>

<div id="container2" class="text2">
  <a id="text2style" href="#" style="font-family:arial;font-size:120%;
text-decoration:none;">text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: All this does is bug out my link. As soon as I hover over it, it rapidly jumps up and down. These two divs are next to each other, side by side. Please look over my code again.

Comment: @H3ll0 Updated my answer. Took out the `bottom` temporary, as they make the boxes disappear in the demo, still, it is the `top: -5px` that makes up for the padding added when hovering, hence keep them from not move downwards

Comment: Your demo shows the text moving to the right. I want the text completely centered, with the padding being the only expansion. Please see the updated code I'll add in a minute.

Comment: @H3ll0 Updated again, text centered all the time

Comment: Please see my updated code. If you could do the same thing but with this different method I've applied, it should really help. I have added the css to an id I created for the links in the divs, instead of applying the transitions to the divs themselves. As explained in the updated post, I now have a right-shift issue and after-fade problem. Would appreciate your input under these new conditions, thank you.

Comment: @H3ll0 Added a 2:nd sample as a reply to your question edit

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/squeLsa6/

```
<div id="" class="box1 container">
<a href="#" style="font-size:120%;text-decoration:none;">Some text</a>
</div>

<div id="" class="box2 container">
<a href="#" style="font-size:120%;text-decoration:none;">text</a>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
.container {
position:relative;
-webkit-transition:color 0.5s;
-o-transition:color 0.5s;
-moz-transition:color 0.5s;
-ms-transition:color 0.5s;
transition:color 0.5s;
-webkit-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-o-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-moz-transition:background-color 0.5s;
-ms-transition:background-color 0.5s;
transition:background-color 0.5s;
padding:5px;
}


a:link, a:visited, a:active {
color:blue;
padding:5px;
}


a:hover {
color:yellow;
padding:5px;
}


.box1 {
left:200px;
bottom:35px;
width:221px;
border-radius:10px;
}


.box2 {
left:455px;
bottom:57px;
width:66px;
border-radius:10px;
}


.container:hover {

background-color:dodgerblue;
}
</style>
```

Basically I moved the padding from the hover state to the a's and the container. I also converted container to be a class, because id's should be unique. I'm not sure exactly how you want it to work, so you may need to play with it a little, but this should get you started.

Comment: I applied it to a link, but now they shift to the right each time I hover.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you confused the id with classes. I changed the name ID with CLASS and it works; In the Css the classes have "." and IDs have "#", be aware of this. When i hover on the div it take a padding of 5px and it is natural that the other div lightly move due to the padding.
If you don't want to move the box you have to give padding anywhere apart of padding-bottom.

Comment: Which IDs do I replace with class?